# Wrap_Content with costume radio button?

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I have made a quiz app but I am facing problems with the radio buttons. I created a rounded background and set it as my radio button background. However, the background doesn't enlarge with the amount of text inside the radio button.

#### Here is an image

I cannot post an image with less than 10 reputation.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVrfd.jpg

My first post here so forgives me for any bad formatting. Thanks in advance for the advice!!

Here is my XML code for a rounded button and for quiz.xml

### rounded_option.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_orange_light" />
            <corners android:radius="150dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

### quiz.xml

```
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_group"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/text_view_question"
        tools:ignore="RelativeOverlap">


        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_option"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Option 1 \n option1 \n option"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
```

#### Activity Code### A bit messy but as asked here is the full code. If I put fragments then the solution will not be found.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.res.ColorStateList;
import android.graphics.Color;


import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;


import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;


import static android.graphics.Color.GREEN;
import static android.graphics.Color.RED;



public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    public static final String EXTRA_SCORE = "extraScore";
    private TextView textViewQuestion;
    private TextView textViewScore;
    private TextView textViewQuestionCount;
    private TextView textViewCorrectAnswer;
    private RadioGroup rbGroup;
    private RadioButton rb1;
    private RadioButton rb2;
    private RadioButton rb3;
    private RadioButton rb4;
    private Button buttonConfirmNext;
    private long backPressedTime;

    private ColorStateList textColorDefaultRb;
    private Drawable textColorDefaultButton;
    private Drawable textColorDefaultAnswer;

    private List<Question> questionList;
    private int questionCounter;
    private int questionCountTotal;
    private Question currentQuestion;

    private int score;
    private boolean answered;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

        textViewQuestion = findViewById(R.id.text_view_question);
        textViewScore = findViewById(R.id.text_view_score);
        textViewCorrectAnswer = findViewById(R.id.text_view_correctAnswer);
        textViewQuestionCount = findViewById(R.id.text_view_question_count);
        rbGroup = findViewById(R.id.radio_group);
        rb1 = findViewById(R.id.radio_button1);
        rb2 = findViewById(R.id.radio_button2);
        rb3 = findViewById(R.id.radio_button3);
        rb4 = findViewById(R.id.radio_button4);

        buttonConfirmNext = findViewById(R.id.button_confirm_next);

        textColorDefaultRb = rb1.getTextColors();
        textColorDefaultButton = rb1.getBackground();


        QuizDbHelper dbHelper = new QuizDbHelper(this);
        questionList = dbHelper.getAllQuestions();
        questionCountTotal = 20;
        Collections.shuffle(questionList);

        showNextQuestion();

        buttonConfirmNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!answered) {
                    if (rb1.isChecked() || rb2.isChecked() || rb3.isChecked() || rb4.isChecked()) {
                        checkAnswer();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Please select an answer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    showNextQuestion();
                    textViewCorrectAnswer.setText("");
                    textViewCorrectAnswer.setBackground(textColorDefaultAnswer);
                }
            }
        });
    }


    private void showNextQuestion() {
        rb1.setTextColor(textColorDefaultRb);
        rb2.setTextColor(textColorDefaultRb);
        rb3.setTextColor(textColorDefaultRb);
        rb4.setTextColor(textColorDefaultRb);


        rb1.setBackground(textColorDefaultButton);
        rb2.setBackground(textColorDefaultButton);
        rb3.setBackground(textColorDefaultButton);
        rb4.setBackground(textColorDefaultButton);


        rbGroup.clearCheck();

        if (questionCounter < questionCountTotal) {
            currentQuestion = questionList.get(questionCounter);

            textViewQuestion.setText(currentQuestion.getQuestion());
            rb1.setText(currentQuestion.getOption1());

            rb2.setText(currentQuestion.getOption2());
            rb3.setText(currentQuestion.getOption3());
            rb4.setText(currentQuestion.getOption4());

            questionCounter++;
            textViewQuestionCount.setText("Question: " + questionCounter + "/" + questionCountTotal);
            answered = false;
            buttonConfirmNext.setText("Confirm");
        } else {
            finishQuiz();
        }
    }

    private void checkAnswer() {
        answered = true;

        RadioButton rbSelected = findViewById(rbGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        int answerNr = rbGroup.indexOfChild(rbSelected) + 1;

        if (answerNr == currentQuestion.getAnswerNr()) {
            score++;
            textViewScore.setText("Score: " + score);
            textViewCorrectAnswer.setText("Your Answer is Correct");
            textViewCorrectAnswer.setTextColor(GREEN);

        }
        else {
            textViewCorrectAnswer.setText("Your Answer is Incorrect");
            textViewCorrectAnswer.setTextColor(RED);
        }
        showSolution();
    }

    private void showSolution() {

        rb1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        rb2.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        rb3.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        rb4.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);


        switch (currentQuestion.getAnswerNr()) {
            case 1:
                rb1.setBackgroundColor(GREEN);

                break;
            case 2:
                rb2.setBackgroundColor(GREEN);


                break;
            case 3:
                rb3.setBackgroundColor(GREEN);


                break;
            case 4:

                rb4.setBackgroundColor(GREEN);


        }

        if (questionCounter < questionCountTotal) {
            buttonConfirmNext.setText("Next");

        } else {
            buttonConfirmNext.setText("Finish");

        }

    }

    private void finishQuiz() {
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
        resultIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_SCORE, score);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (backPressedTime + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
            finishQuiz();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Press back again to finish", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        backPressedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you showing 4 option's In one radio Button?

Comment: No, I just included the code for 1 button as it is just repetitive. I have 1 button assigned to each option.

Answer (score 0):

check this out : replace items as you need .

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="250dp">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_group"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:ignore="RelativeOverlap">


        <RadioButton
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_option"
            android:id="@+id/radio_button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="afeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeesdfsfsdfsdfsfsdsfddddddddddddddddddddddsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdffsdffsdfsdfdsf"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
    </RadioGroup>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the screenshot :
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply but this solution makes the background square which is not something I am looking for. The auto-size works when the radio button has a normal background(no rounded corners) but if you see my image the rounded corner radio button doesn't resize all the time (if it does then it resizes wrong hence leaving a word or a line outside the bg). I think this solution will be the last resort to my problem if I don't find out what I can do.

Comment: @RocoPi Check now .

Comment: That is what I have as well but when I run the code and the options get pulled from the database then the background behaves very weirdly.

Comment: There is something different with your layout . Did you notice that? Can you please run you app and see if it work or not . It will great if you can provide a ss after read from database?

Comment: Do you mean my layout of code? I ran the app with the same code that you provided and it still has the issue. The screenshot before is from the actual app running. But here are two screenshots one is before running one is after.  [Before running](https://imgur.com/UIiDqFF)  [After running the app](https://imgur.com/nZ9balm)

Comment: Look textsize just changed . Can you share the activity code?

Comment: I added the activity code. I think I might get what the problem is. maybe it is because I am setting my background using 
```JAVA
getbackground
```.